# Integrating visual guide within cell to hide / unhide rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

I have 5 rows of data and want to hide 4 of them.

This macro works but seems to be a bit unstable. And one has to click out of the cell `J8` and then back into it for it to work.

In addition, it doesn't seem to work to double click on it when it has text in it. And when you set this up it prevents the cell from auto-adjusting its height.

Most importantly a user would be unlikely to know that this was possible to do as there are no visual cues within the cell that you can double click on it and it un-hides the rows / hides the rows. Are there other options?

I've done a ton of searching and haven't been able to find a better solution.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim xRgHidden As Range
    If (Not Intersect(Target, Range("J8")) Is Nothing) And (Target.Count = 1) Then
        Set xRgHidden = Range("9:12")
        xRgHidden.EntireRow.Hidden = Not xRgHidden.EntireRow.Hidden
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

***First,*** to get rid from Clicking out of `J8` to un-hide rows.

- When you Double Click any cell, Excel switch to **Edit Mode** (`you find the cursor in the cell, Double clicked On`).
- Add this code as row nu 4 (`after If (Not Intersect` row).

  `Cancel = True`

***Second,*** to get visuals while hit `J8` to Hide & Un-Hide Rows.

- Select cell `J8`, **R**ight Click, and from **P**op Up menu hit **I**nsert Comment.
- Insert an appropriate text, will appear when you hover cell `J8`.